# How can I extract a particular bit in Java?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I need a specific bit in a byte value stored as int value. My code is as shown below.

```
private int getBitValue(int byteVal, int bitShift){
    byteVal = byteVal << bitShift;
    int bit = (int) (byteVal >>>7);
    return bit;
}
```

It is working when I give the bitshift as 1 but when I give the bitshift as 2 and the byteVal as 67(01000011 in binary), I get the value of 'byteVal' as 268 while 'byteVal' should be 3(000011 in binary) after the first line in the method(the left shift). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not clear what `getBitValue` is supposed to do: do you want the low `bitShift` bits?

Comment: A bit is usually 1 bit, and a byte is usually 8 bits. I don't see how shifting by 7 bits comes into it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey my logic is like if i shift right by 7 bits, the result int value will be equal to the most significant bit of  'byteVal'.

Comment: But `int` has 32 bits, so it would make sense if you did `byteVal >>> -1` or `byteVal >>> 31`  But then you would nee to shift left by `byteVal << -bitShift`

Comment: @PeterLawrey i understand the error i am making here now. if i change the type of byteVal to byte instead of int, will this code work as I expect it to?

Comment: You could do that, but you might just confuse yourself as there is no bit shift operations for byte, short, or char. In each case, the number is extended to an int.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason when I try your code I don't get what you get. For your example, if you say `byteVal = 0b01000011` and `bitShift = 2`, then this is what I get:

```
byteVal = 0b01000011 << 2 = 0b0100001100
bit = (int) (0b0100001100 >>> 7) = (int) (0b010) // redundant cast
returned value: 0b010 == 2
```

I believe what you intended to do was shift the bit you wanted to the leftmost position, and then shift it all the way to the right to get the bit. However, your code won't do that for a few reasons:

1. You need to shift left by `(variable length - bitShift)` to get the desired bit to the place you want. So in this case, what you really want is to shift `byteVal` left by **6** places, not 2.
2. `int` variables are 32 bits wide, not 8. (so you actually want to shift `byteVal` left by **30** places)

In addition, your question appears to be somewhat contradictory. You state you want a specific bit, yet your example implies you want the `bitShift`-th least significant bits.

An easier way of getting a specific bit might be to simply shift right as far as you need and then mask with 1: (also, you can't use `return` with `void`, but I'm assuming that was a typo)

```
private int getBitValue(int byteVal, int bitShift) {
    byteVal = byteVal >> bitShift; // makes the bitShift-th bit the rightmost bit
                                   // Assumes bit numbers are 0-based (i.e. original rightmost bit is the 0th bit)
    return (int) (byteVal & 1) // AND the result with 1, which keeps only the rightmost bit
}
```

If you want the `bitShift`-th least significant bits, I believe something like this would work:

```
private int getNthLSBits(int byteVal, int numBits) {
    return byteVal & ((1 << numBits) - 1);
    // ((1 << numBits) - 1) gives you numBits ones
    // i.e. if numBits = 3, (1 << numBits) - 1 == 0b111
    // AND that with byteVal to get the numBits-th least significant bits
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why the answer should be 3 and I think we need more information on what the function should do.

Assuming you want the value of the byteVal's lowest bitShift bits, I'd do the following.

```
private int getBitValue(int byteVal, int bitShift){
    int mask = 1 << bitShift;  // mask = 1000.... (number of 0's = bitShift)
    mask--;                     // mask = 000011111 (number of 1's = bitShift)
    return (byteVal & mask);
}
```

At the very least, this function will return 1 for getBitValue(67, 1) and 3 for getBitValue(67,2).